# Проблема с StreamWriter. Вывод переменной в файл

Tags: c#

Вот кусок кода -

```
Console.WriteLine(s);
a = Console.ReadLine();
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"C:\kardlnal\i.txt");
StreamWriter w = f.CreateText();
w.WriteLine(a);
w.Close();
```

Все вроде работает, но есть одно но. Это действие заключено в цикле, после каждого запуска переменная `s` меняет значения и так же, после каждого запуска, в файле `C:\kardlnal\i.txt` стирается то, что было написано раньше. Мне же надо, чтобы эта команда дописывала, а не переписывала все заново.
Возможно так сделать или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, создавать `FileInfo` нет смысла.

`StreamWriter` вторым параметром принимает `append`, который можно задать в `true` и тогда значения будут добавляться в файл.

```
using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"C:\kardlnal\i.txt", true))
{
    w.WriteLine(a);
}
```

В третьих, если у Вас в цикле всё записывается, то зачем Вам на каждой итерации заново создавать `StreamWriter`? Почему бы его не создать до цикла и закрыть после?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно возможно.
Например так:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\kardlnal\i.txt", FileMode.Append))
using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    w.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Здесь вторым аргументом [конструктора `FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx) передается режим открытия файла - [`FileMode.Append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx).